# Yii2 and TimescaleDB: GridView very slow on large Table

Tags: postgresql, performance, gridview, yii2, timescaledb

Using Yii2 with TimescaleDB (PostgreSQL Extension for time series data) gets very slow on large tables (> 1 billion rows).

I think that comes from the function `getTotalCount()`in [`yii\data\BaseDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider#getTotalCount()-detail) which gets called to provide pagination on every page.

We know from [TimescaleDB that row counting on large tables gets very slow](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/525). If we replace the function `getTotalCount()` in the model by a "coorrect" solution as

```
static public function getTotalCount()
{
    $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
    $command = $connection->createCommand("
        SELECT h.schema_name,
            h.table_name,
            h.id AS table_id,
            h.associated_table_prefix,
            row_estimate.row_estimate
        FROM _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable h
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT sum(cl.reltuples) AS row_estimate
        FROM _timescaledb_catalog.chunk c
        JOIN pg_class cl ON cl.relname = c.table_name
        WHERE c.hypertable_id = h.id and h.table_name = 'value'
        GROUP BY h.schema_name, h.table_name) row_estimate
        ORDER BY \"schema_name\", \"table_name\";
    ");

    $result = $command->queryAll();
    return floatval($result[0]["row_estimate"]);
}
```

But do we really have to perform this query for pagination?

This seems quite complex. How to optimize this? Maybe just by returning a very large but fixed number since nobody needs pagination over a billion pages?

Example:

```
const LARGE_NUM = 1000;
static public function getTotalCount() 
{
    if (Yii::$app->session->get("mytable-rows")>MyClass::LARGE_NUM) {
        return MyClass::LARGE_NUM; 
    } 
    $totalRows = parent::getTotalCount();
    Yii::$app->session->set("mytable-rows",$totalRows);
    return $totalRows;
}
```

Is this a valid and fast solution? Are the dangerous side effects?

Comment: Do you need to use pagination for first few pages or are you not using the pagination at all? If you don't need pagination then setting `$pagination` property of `BaseDataProvider` to `false` should prevent the `getTotalCount()` method calls from GridView.

Comment: I need pagination but only for the first 50 pages or so.

Comment: Maybe you can get the pages without using count/offset: e.g. use `WHERE date_time > $start LIMIT $pagesize`. For the first, call `start` is undefined (so you have just the limit clause) and when the user clicks the next-page button `start` is the latest date that was shown in the current page. But I don't know if your grid-component/framework supports this.

Comment: @WeSee so what about overriding the `getTotalCount` to store total count in cache? [Cache docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data#data-caching). It's better than using session because sessions have short live and they are not shared among users. You can also make some action executed by cron that would update the stored total count in backgroud.

Comment: @TmTron that wouldn't help.  You would need to implement your own pagination component for that and you would still need to get total row count to calculate the total number of pages or to display the total number of records in summary.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Well, I think that the total number of rows is not relevant in this case, as the OP mentioned, that they only need `the first 50 pages or so`. In that case it would maybe be enough at some point to indicate that there is no more data. This approach only allows to go to the next/prev. page (but not to a random page by number): so it's not a true "pagination" and may not be supported out-of-the-box by some grids/frameworks.

Comment: @TmTron it is relevant because they are using the GridView component of yii2 framework. That component uses the pagination implemented in framework and both components (grid view and pagination) are relying on the `getTotalCount` method. So it's better to optimize the performance of `getTotalCount` because replacing the pagination would be much more work.